# T-Mobile Prism won't boot

Tags: boot

My t-mobile prism, will not turn on. It is unrooted. The only thing that happens is the backlight for the screen comes on and the buttons light up. When I try and boot it into recovery mode. Nothing happens when I press the volume buttons and the power button together. Can anyone help? It's been like this for 2 days, I have left it on and off the charger hours and no change.